# Dropdown abrindo com click

Tags: javascript, css, dropdown

como vai?

Então, estou tentando desapegar do bootstrap nesse projeto que estou fazendo (para melhorar minhas práticas front-end e também pq eu já fiz grande parte dos estilos do site, se eu implementasse bootstrap estragaria tudo). Estou querendo criar um dropdown que funciona com o click, da mesma forma do bootstrap, que dá pra usar em qualquer caso, e na maioria, na realidade, em todos, é muito básico. Eu encontrei esse: http://www.w3schools...js_dropdown.asp, eu até implementei para dar para usar em qualquer caso (em várias partes do site, não só no menu), mas o problema é que quando se ativa dois, os dois ficam ativos, e a ideia é só um ser ativo por vez. Os outros tutoriais só servem para menu em um único caso. Eu tava pensando se seria possível pegar apenas "partes" do bootstrap, já que eu não usaria tudo e só pesaria o carregamento do site. Enfim, algum mestre em front-end que poderia ajudar? Se ainda ficou em dúvida, é algo como a barra que tem as notificações, e mensagens no facebook, é esse comportamento...

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dentro do próprio site do bootstrap você pode desabilitar todos os recursos menos o dropdown, segue o link: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

depois é só ir ao final da página e compilar.

Comment: Valeu Iago, era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando!